# Keep the code running Even If I closed the Visual studio code app - Python language

Tags: python, visual-studio, telegram, telegram-bot, keep-alive

I will keep it short. I built a Telegram bot using python on visual studio code. I want the code **to keep running even if I close the app **or my laptop. But unfortunately, when I turn off my computer it will stop working on my Telegram bot.

I used ChatGPT as an assistant. And when I turn off my computer the bot features will be hidden. I tried to use some codes to keep it running, but it's useless. I'm not an expert so may anyone help.

Comment: When you turn off your computer **everything** will stop running. What were you expecting?

Comment: if your laptop is not runing how do you expect your script to keep running? You need to host it somewhere that is up and running.

Answer (score 0):

When you shut down your computer, all the programs that were running on it will stop running. So, if you have a program and you want to run it all the time, then you will either need to keep your computer operational so that the program can run on it, or copy and run your program to another computer that will serve the purposes of a server and will run indefinitely.

If you run it for Visual Studio Code, such as in the case of [telethon-vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xditya.telethon), then you will need to run the program to which this is an extension. You need to ask yourself why you want this to run when your computer / VSC are off and decide the path forward for yourself based on your answer to that one.

Comment: Because it's like buttons that each member will see when they join. So that's why I need to keep it running. But these solutions are confusing hahaha.